# importing sass variables from jsx file

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I'm working on a React project built with `create-react-app`. I have a file called `common.scss` where I keep a list of variables, for example:

```
$blue: 'blue';
$red: 'red';
```

The SCSS files are pre-processed with `node-sass-chokidar`.

I would like to be able to import these variables into my jsx files, but I could not find a clear way of doing this without ejecting. Can you show me a way to do this without eject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/icss), you can import a css file with some variables exported.

```
$blue: 'blue';
$red: 'red';

:export {
  blue: $blue;
  red: $red;
}
```

And then use them as js.

```
import css from 'path/to/your/file.scss'
/*
...
*/
<div style={{color: css.blue}} />
```

Comment: Its not straight forward, atleast not for my project, using the same pre-processor

Comment: Just make sure you’ve got css modules turned on when compiling.